# Embed svg icon as external file link in adobe illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I would like to link icons into svg as external source.
The reason is that I change this images on client side with javascript.

If icons are jpg or png or similar, I can click "Link" checkbox when place external file. But my icons are in svg format. And checxbox is disabled when I would like to place the svg as external link. I need to have icons as svg since I change also color on the client side(beside different icon).

How can I embed svg icon as external file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not about programming as stated in the [help/on-topic]. It may better fit on [graphicdesign.se], but make sure to include an image of your attempt.

Comment: Hi, how can I place this question into graphic design? When I have asked the question I didn't see any option to select different category.

Comment: To submit questions on GD you can go to the main page and sign in as usual: "We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites." Your current account will automatically be extended to GD, and it will appear in the drop down list on the left of the top menu bar under "Your communities".

Comment: Thank you. I din't know that.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to do this with adobe illustrator. The workaround is to link to some jpg and then open svg file in notepad and replace external jpg link to external svg link. This way it works.